# How to export picture from rxgraph?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When my rxgraph's graph is larger than my screen,it is difficult to save to picture format.
How to do that?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10569/how-to-export-picture-from-rxgraph?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just run:

```
rxgraph -o rxgraph.dot
dot -T png -o output.png rxgraph.dot
```

Instead of PNG, you can use any [output format supported by graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-24**:
how to save rxgraph along with the information coloumn (for all nodes) on the right side?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-24**:
The only way I can think of for doing that is a screenshot.